# A question about natural epimorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My question came from a proof of a proposition about perfect groups, it quote it here:

> Let $N$ be an Abelian normal subgroup of $G$. If $G/N$ is perfect,
>   then also $G'$ is perfect.

At the beginning of the proof, it writes that

> From the fact that $[x,y]^\varphi=[x^\varphi,y^\varphi]\Longrightarrow (G')^\varphi=(G^\varphi)'$, applied to the ***natural epimorphism***, we obtain
>   $$G/N={\color{red}{(G/N)'=G'N/N}}.$$

I think the $\varphi$ here can refer to the ***natural epimorphism***; however, I think it should be ${\color{red}{G'/N}}$, not ${\color{red}{G'N/N}}$, but in that way, since $N$ is not necessarily contained in $G'$, it will contradict the requirement of ***natural epimorphism*** that $N\trianglelefteq G'$. Both sides seem unreasonable to me.

I'm now completely confused, how can it be $G'N/N$?

Is my question clear? Any help will be sincerely appreciated!

**PS:** It’s on page 25 of [my textbook](http://www.math.ku.dk/~olsson/manus/GruFus/Kurzweil-Stellmacher_Theory%20of%20finite%20groups.pdf).

Comment: I'm trying to fathom the motivation to write the application of a homomorphism "exponentially"...

Comment: @DerekElkins Whichever is ok : )

Comment: @DerekElkins I am quite sure that the exponential notation is for conjugation (inner automorphism).

Comment: @DerekElkins  $a^\varphi=\varphi(a)$, where $\varphi$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: @IgorRivin Then you are quite wrong (in this case). Look at section 1.2 of the referenced PDF.

Comment: @DerekElkins I eat my words. This notation is stupid (*especially* because the exponential notation is commonly used for conjugation).

Comment: @IgorRivin Not exactly so, I found both conventions are usually used.

Comment: @IgorRivin, [re](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2678792/a-question-about-natural-epimorphism#comment5532452_2678792), I think that the motivation is that every group $G$ embeds in its [holomorph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorph_(mathematics)), in which all automorphisms of $G$ become inner, so that applying an automorphism of $G$ can literally be viewed as conjugation (in an overgroup).  But there is no justification for it being on the wrong side to be an action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic words are "Second Isomorphism Theorem".

Comment: THANKS! I know the theorem. How can it help me? The theorem is applied later in the proof, so this theorem might not be the key here to my question. What have I missed?

Comment: Look at the statement of the theorem, which tells you that $G^\prime N/N = G^\prime/(G^\prime \cap N).$  So, you need to check that $(G/N)^\prime = G^\prime/(G^\prime \cap N).$ But the RHS is just $\phi(G^\prime),$ while the LHS is $(\phi(G))^\prime.$

Comment: @Benny which you know are the same.

Answer (score 1):

When you write $G'/N$, you must make sure $N\unlhd G'$. So you must have $N\subset G'$. But here we don't necessarily have that.

Let $\varphi:G\to G/N$ with $\varphi(g)=gN$.

Claim: $\varphi(G')=G'N/N$.

Proof. Since $N\unlhd G'N$, $G'N/N$ is well defined. Let $g\in G'$, then $\varphi(g)=gN\in G'N/N$. Conversely, let $gnN\in G'N/N$. Then $gnN=gN=\varphi(g)\in \varphi(G')$.

As mentioned in the comments above, this is in 1.2.6 in your textbook.

Comment: I may have thought in the very same way, if the equation on page 25 wasn’t given so directly. Thanks, you got what I exactly want to know!